# phpunit2 "Not tests executed"

Tags: php, unit-testing, xampp, phpunit

Hey i got a little problem.

If i use phpunit i can run my test but if i try to use phpunit2 it doesnt work.

It seems like it cant find the tests.

I only get the message: "No Tests executed".

I'm using **xamp** with **pear 1.9.4, php 5.5.9 zend 2.5.0.**

The files are in the **xampp/php** folder where the phpunit.bat is.

**BankAccount.php**

```
<?php
class BankAccount {
  private $fBalance = 0;

  public function getBalance() {
    return $this->fBalance;
  }

  public function setBalance($balance) {
    if ($balance >= 0) {
      $this->fBalance = $balance;
    }
  }

  public function depositMoney($amount) {
    if (is_numeric($amount) &&
      $amount >= 0) {
      $this->fBalance += $amount;
    }
  }

  public function withdrawMoney($amount) {
    if (is_numeric($amount) &&
      $amount >= 0 &&
      $this->fBalance >= $amount) {
      $this->fBalance -= $amount;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

**BankAccountTest.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'BankAccount.php'; // zu testende Klasse
require_once 'PHPUnit2/Framework/TestCase.php'; // Einbinden der Pear-Klasse

class BankAccountTest extends PHPUnit2_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testBalanceIsInitiallyZero() {
    $ba = new BankAccount;
    $this->assertEquals(0, $ba->getBalance());
  }

  public function testBalanceCannotBecomeNegative() {
    $ba = new BankAccount;
    $ba->withdrawMoney(1);
    $this->assertEquals(0, $ba->getBalance());

    $ba = new BankAccount;
    $ba->setBalance(-1);
    $this->assertEquals(0, $ba->getBalance());
  }
}
?>
```

Any help highly appreciated!..

Comment: I don't understand why you are extending `PHPUnit2_Framework_TestCase`. You must extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: doesnt i use unit for php4 and unit2 for php5 or am i completly wrong? i saw phpunit2 i multiple examples or are they older versions and its enough to simply use phpunit?

Comment: try it with `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Comment: i have tested PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase already before and that worked. but for what is phpunit2 if i doesnt use it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from [PHP Cookbook by Adam Trachtenberg and David Sklar, Page 619:](http://books.google.es/books?id=P1wJRrE8KjYC&pg=PA619&lpg=PA619&dq=phpunit%20vs%20phpunit2&source=bl&ots=-kWo_UJg8N&sig=xuvImDP1xHL_lW9HSnHPJnkSdtM&hl=es&sa=X&ei=7UegU6-pOMH80QX3lIDYCw&ved=0CHgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=phpunit%20vs%20phpunit2&f=false)

> PHPUnit2 is for PHP5 only, whereas PHPUnit will work under PHP5 or
>   PHP4.

---

*In conclusion:* You can use `PHPUnit2_Framework_TestCase` to test your code. But for simplicity, and because of the problems you have now, just use `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.